# Can't build command line project with SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, xcode7, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to build a command-line tool which uses sqlite.  I have downloaded [Stephen Celis' swift wrapper, SQLite.swift,](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) and built a working OS X app.  However, I am not able to build my command-line tool.  I believe that I correctly followed the instructions to do so in the [SQLite.swift Documentation for frameworkless targets](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#frameworkless-targets), but apparently I am missing something.  I get an error in Helper.swift @ import CSQLite -> No such module 'CSQLite'.

- I am linking against libsqlite3.dylib (also tried libsqlite3.tbd)
- I added the SQLite.swift source to my project
- I added #import sqlite3.h & #import "SQLite-Bridging.h" to my    bridging header file. Perhaps of note, when I right-click on sqlite3.h or       SQLite-Bridging.h, xCode does not know where/what they are.

I'm happy to send my test project (about 80KB, compressed) to anyone who can and is willing to help.  There is probably a very simple solution, I just do not see what it is.

thx for any help,

-Craig

Comment: My Objective-C Bridging Header (xxx-Bridging-Header.h) for some reason did not get added properly to the project.  Also, I had to comment out import CSQLite in three files: Connection, Helpers, and Statement.  Project now  builds and runs.

Answer (score 5):

I've faced the same problem.
There were lots of compiler errors like "Connection.swift:26:8: Could not build Objective-C module 'CSQLite'"

The error has roots to the "lctx.h:13:25: Use of undeclared identifier 'SYS_getlcid'"

It worth mentioning that I have two Xcodes installed - v 6.2 at /Applications and v 7.3 at ~/Applications. My project is iOS app on Swift with SQLite pod and I open it with the Xcode 7.3.

The SQLite pod has a file at project_folder/Pods/SQLite.swift/CocoaPods/iphonesimulator/module.modulemap.
The file had the content

`module CSQLite [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
    export *
}`

To fix compiler errors I changed the content of module.modulemap to

`module CSQLite [system] {
    header "/Users/my_user_name/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
    export *
}`

The change is that I pointed search of sqlite3.h into my ~/Applications folder where Xcode 7.3 is located.
This made my project compiling.

Comment: In my case, I have two Xcodes, 8 and 7.3 alongside. I have renamed the 7.3 as Xcode_7. Then I needed to change the "Xcode.app" in the modulemap path to "Xcode_7.app". Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much. Save me